# Roblox CFrame lookVector isn't moving part?

Tags: math, lua, roblox

I've recently been working a lot with CFrame mechanics while scripting and I've got kind of stuck on this.

Even after using `.lookVector`, or even `Vector3`, the Jetpack model position stays equal to the position of the Torso instead of 5 `(* -5)` behind the torso.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
local player = script.Parent
local jetpack = game.ReplicatedStorage.Jetpack
local jetpackClone = jetpack:Clone()
jetpackClone.PrimaryPart = jetpackClone.Core
jetpackClone.Parent = player
jetpackClone:moveTo(player.Torso.Position + player.Torso.CFrame.lookVector * -5)

local weld = Instance.new("Motor6D")
weld.Parent = jetpackClone.Core
weld.Part0 = jetpackClone.Core
weld.Part1 = player.Torso
```

Comment: Are you sure the position isn't already stored in `Torso.Position` as I'm pretty certain it's in one of the trailing numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by trailing numbers @Taazar Sorry for not understanding, as I am pretty new to scripting.

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix this is quite simple.

Like Ahmad said, moveTo is used for models that doesn't have a primary part. But it is not only that.

One thing that Ahmad forgot is that 'lookVector' is not a CFrame, it is a Vector3 instead.

In this fragment, you did

```
moveTo(player.Torso.Position + player.Torso.CFrame.lookVector * -5)
```

That would be fine, if you didn't use a numerical value with Vector3's. To fix this, instead, your code should be

```
local player = script.Parent
local jetpack = game.ReplicatedStorage.Jetpack;
local jetpackClone = jetpack:Clone();
jetpackClone.PrimaryPart = jetpackClone.Core;
jetpackClone.Parent = player; -- Is the 'Player' a Player, or a character??

local weld = Instance.new("Weld", player.Torso) -- We use 'Weld' here, instead of Motor6D
weld.Part1 = jetpackClone.Core;
weld.Part0 = player.Torso;
weld.C0 = CFrame.new(0, 0, -5); -- We use the C0 property of Weld's
```

That should do it for welding the jetpack to your torso. Though, I would check if the CFrame is correct in it, I am not sure if it is or not, but if the jetpack appears in front of your torso, then replace `weld.C0 = CFrame.new(0, 0, -5)` to `weld.C0 = CFrame.new(0, 0, 5)`.

Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

**moveTo** is used for models that doesn't have a primary part. Which can be inaccurate. Instead use `:SetPrimaryPartCFrame()` also u were adding Position+CFrame(it would cause an error did u check output?)